# "No improvement whatsoever" for tag wikis nobody uses?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

The description for "no improvement whatsoever" reads like this:

> **no improvement whatsoever** This edit fails to make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I have been using this for edits to tag wikis that have very few questions or followers, since populating such wikis make posts no easier to read, no easier to find, no more accessible, and I'm generally unable to judge whether they're accurate.

Should I continue doing this or should I change my behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many tags may start out with few questions and followers; don't take the current question and follower count as an indication of the usefulness of a tag wiki!

Yes, you should stop using that rejection reason. If a tag wiki edit follows the guidelines and leads to a tag wiki that tells the reader what to use the tag for, then the edit is helpful and should be applied.

Comment: OK.  I've seen a few that have looked like attempts to advertise a product, which is what led me into this behaviour.  Should I stop being concerned about this in tag wikis?  If so, I understand what to do.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Well, now you're asking a different question.

Comment: @tmyklebu: that's something different entirely. If you see tags that you feel are being added to promote a product, either flag a post with such a tag for moderator attention or start a Meta post to discuss the issue for those specific tags.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You're right; the question in that comment is not what I meant to ask.  Trying again:  Should I continue letting "very few questions or followers" help inform whether something's informative or promotional in nature?

Comment: @tmyklebu: No.  The number of followers of a tag wiki doesn't have anything to do with an edit's quality.  We *want* people to fill in tag wikis, not wait until they become popular to do so.

Comment: @tmyklebu: That's still a different question. And the follower and question counts still don't apply there; overt product promotions are not helpful in any tag wiki, regardless of counts.